# Not able to retrieve JSESSIONID cookie with AXIOS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, axios

I am trying to call API to authenticate user. getting 200 success response but not getting JSESSIONID cookie in response.

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = 'true';
axios.defaults.crossDomain = 'true';
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
axios.defaults.headers.post['withCredentials'] = 'true';
const data = {
          username: this.state.user,
          credential: this.state.pass
        }

        axios.post('http://3.122.7.162:5000/v60/admin/session', data)
        .then(response => {
          console.log("response");
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log("error");
          console.log(error);
        });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`XMLHttpRequest` and `fetch` (the built-in HTTP request libraries in browsers) do not expose information about cookies in their response object.

It isn't even available through directly reading the `Set-Cookie` header because it is [a forbidden response header](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name).

The only way to read cookie data is through `document.cookie`, but that only provides information about **same** origin cookies.

There is no direct way to get the data from a cross-origin cookie using Ajax methods. The only way to do it would be to change the server side code so it returned a copy of the cookie data through another path that the JavaScript could read (e.g. in the response body).

---

This doesn't stop you *using* the cookies. Unless third-party cookies are disabled, they will still be set in the browser's cookie jar and automatically sent with future requests to the domain they belong to.